# Issue with xml layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, editor

Suddenly my editor became blue and the icon change to blue some body know why?
[image]

Comment: Android studio while indexing some how inserted type as plain_text that's why you are seeing this error.

Comment: go to ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioX.X/options/venta_layout.xml and change the type to XML

Comment: where is library?? well anyway I fix it invoquing the contextual menu and selecting mark as xml

Comment: I was giving you path with respect Mac, anyways problem was some how indexing got corrupted and it was marked as plain text as type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By mistake, the file has been marked as Plain text.

Do following:

```
Right click Venta_layout file -> Find "Mark as XML" option
```

You can find it here:-

[image]

Comment: Yes i have do this